# Where can I locate the actual files of Kubernates PV hostpath

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I just created the following PersistantVolume.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: sql-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/var/lib/sqldata"
```

Then I SSH the Node and traversed to the `/var/lib`. But I cannot see the `sqldata` directory created anywhere in it.

Where is the real directory created?

I created a POD that mounts this volume to a path inside the container. When I SSH the container, I can see the file in the mount path. Where are these files stored?

Comment: Doesn't that directory need to exist before you create that PV?

Comment: The creation of the PV didn't return any error. Also, I created a claim and used it in a POD spec. No error still.

Comment: @Jonas I found the directory in the VM. It was not found in the Node when I SSH, I saw the VM and the Node are two different systems. Is this correct?

Comment: That depends on how you run Kubernetes. It can be run on local machine, on bare-metal server or on VM server.

Comment: It is directly in GCP. I really thought the GCP VM is the Node itself.

Comment: If it's on GCP (and especially if it's in GKE) you should probably create a PersistentVolumeClaim, but not explicitly create a PersistentVolume.  A `hostPath` volume in particular will resolve to that path on whichever node the pod is running on, which means you'll lose (or at least misplace) data if the pod is recreated on a different node.  The default volume provisioner in a cloud environment should give you a cloud-hosted volume that can follow the pod around.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the insight. This is a single node cluster and this is why I thought  I can use the hostpath,.

However, I very much welcome your suggestion of creating a PVC without an explicit PV.  It still matches my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have setup your cluster on [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine), that means **nodes are virtual machine instances on GCP**. You've probably been connecting to the cluster using the Kubernetes Engine dashboard and `Connect to the cluster` option. It does not SSH you to any of the node, it just starting GCP Cloud Shell terminal instance with following command like:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials {your-cluster} --zone {your-zone} --project {your-project-name}
```

That command is configuring [`kubectl` agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) on GCP Cloud Shell by [setting proper cluster name, certificates etc. in `~/.kube/config` file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) so you have access to the cluster (by [communicating with the cluster endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#cluster_endpoint)), but **you are not SSHed to any node**. That's why you can't access the path defined in the `hostPath`.

To find a hostPath directory, you need to:

- find on which node is the pod
- SSH into this node

**Finding a node**:

Run following  `kubectl get pod {pod-name}` with `-o wide` flag command  - change `{pod-name}` to your pod name

```
user@cloudshell:~ (project)$ kubectl get pod task-pv-pod -o wide
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
task-pv-pod   1/1     Running   0          53m   xx.xx.x.xxx   gke-test-v-1-21-default-pool-82dbc10b-8mvx   <none>           <none>
```

**SSH to the node**:

Run following `gcloud compute ssh {cluster-name}` command - change `{cluster-name}` to node name from the previous command:

```
user@cloudshell:~ (project)$ gcloud compute ssh gke-test-v-1-21-default-pool-82dbc10b-8mvx

Welcome to Kubernetes v1.21.3-gke.2001!

You can find documentation for Kubernetes at:
  http://docs.kubernetes.io/

The source for this release can be found at:
  /home/kubernetes/kubernetes-src.tar.gz
Or you can download it at:
  https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release-gke/release/v1.21.3-gke.2001/kubernetes-src.tar.gz

It is based on the Kubernetes source at:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/v1.21.3-gke.2001

For Kubernetes copyright and licensing information, see:
  /home/kubernetes/LICENSES

user@gke-test-v-1-21-default-pool-82dbc10b-8mvx ~ $
```

Now there will be a  `hostPath` directory (in your case `/var/lib/sqldata`), there will also be files if pod created some.

---

#### Avoid hostPath if possible

It's not recommended using `hostPath`. As mentioned in the comments, it will cause issues when a pod will be created on the different node (but you have a single node cluster) but it also [presents many security risks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath):

> **Warning:**
> HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as ReadOnly.
> If restricting HostPath access to specific directories through AdmissionPolicy,  `volumeMounts`  MUST be required to use  `readOnly`  mounts for the policy to be effective.

In your case it's much better to use the `gcePersistentDisk`volume type - check [this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I never knew that the console was connecting to the cloud shell.